# Why does element UI exist OR how can I create a v-if v-else for my profile image column

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

How to write an v-if v-else using EL-table for just my photo column so that when a photo exist in the DB, I can see that image and when there is none I can point to my stock image?

I have a column generated by an EL-table for my profile pics. However, some items do not have pics... I have a default image in a subfolder that contains a placeholder image.

How to write an v-if v-else using EL-table for just my photo column?

(Aside: if this were basic HTML I'd be done by now. But this code base is using an HTML wrapper library of some sort called Element UI).

Here is the table column in question:

```
<el-table-column v-for="column in tableColumns"
      :key="column.label"
      :min-width="column.minWidth"
      :prop="column.prop"
      :label="column.label">
</el-table-column>
```

and tableColumns is being fed these values:

```
tableColumns: [
      {
        prop: 'photo',
        label: 'Pic',
        minWidth: 100
      },
      {
        prop: 'name',
        label: 'Name',
        minWidth: 200
      },
      {
        prop: 'gender',
        label: 'Gender',
        minWidth: 250
      },
      {
        prop: 'age',
        label: 'Age',
        minWidth: 100
      },
      {
        prop: 'cat_type',
        label: 'Type',
        minWidth: 120
      }
 ],
```

Again, how to write an v-if v-else using EL-table for just my photo column so that when a photo exist in the DB, I can see that image and when there is none I can point to my stock image ?

Something like this:

```
<template slot-scope="props">
   <a v-tooltip.top-center="'Like'" class="btn-info btn-simple btn-link" @click="handleLike(props.$index, props.row)">
   <!--TODO: small profile pic-->
   <div class="col-md-2 img-container photo-thumb-sm" v-if="props.row.photo !== null">
       <img :src="props.row.photo" alt="thumb" class="rounded-circle img-fluid max-width: 100%;height: auto;">
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-2 img-container photo-thumb-sm" v-else>
        <img src="/static/img/bastet.png" alt="bastet">
   </div>
 </a>
</template>
```

I'm new to Element UI, and I'm stuck with it.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not Element UI fault, maybe you can check props.row.photo !== null, really null? 
another way, check src="/static/img/bastet.png" true path ?

Comment: Ah, I should be more specific. some of the records have a profile photo on purpose. The others do not as no photo was uploaded for them. So I need to write an if / else for when the records do or do not have an image.